# Error defining free_func for SList from GLib

Tags: c, free, glib

I have a [GSList](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.SList.html) of structs of type `Test` as defined below:

```c
typedef struct test {
    char *a;
    char *b;
    char *c;
} Test;
```

I'm trying to free this GSList with [g_slist_free_full](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/type_func.SList.free_full.html). Function signature:

`void g_slist_free_full(GSList* list, GDestroyNotify free_func)`

But I'm having trouble defining the `free_func` function responsible for freeing each element of the GSList. So far I have:

```c
void free_test(void *test)
{
    Test *t = (Test *)test;
    free(t->a);
    free(t->b);
    free(t->c);
    free(t);
}
```

This definition always fails at the **second** free (`free(t->b)`). The errors seem to vary, but it's mostly:

```
free(): invalid pointer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

But I've also seen `Segmentation fault` and `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`.

I've noticed that if I print the string b after freeing the string a, string b will have it's first characters modified.

Comment: I now see that the error was probably done when I did `test->a = buff` instead of allocating memory do `test->a` and then copying `buff` to `test->a`.

Comment: Still wouldn't mind an explanation from someone who actually know what's going on.

Comment: This question probably isn't answerable unless we know how you populated the struct that gets passed to `free_test`.

Comment: @ptomato at first I was just assigning each element of the struct to the return pointer of `strsep`. Now I'm actually allocating space for each element and copying the return of `strsep` to it with `strcpy`. Now it works, but I can't say I really understand why.

Comment: `strsep` doesn't allocate a string for its return value, it returns a pointer inside an already-allocated string. So you can't free those pointers.